# Iterative programming using PCollectionViews

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I wish to create a PCollection of say one hundred thousand objects (maybe even a million) such that I apply an operation on it a million times in a for-loop on the same data, but with DIFFERENT values for the PCollectionView calculated on each iteration of the loop. **Is this a use-case that df can handle reasonably well? Is there a better way to achieve this?** My concerns is that PCollectionView has too much overhead, but it could be that that used to be a problem a year ago but now this a use-case that DF can support well. In my case, I can hardcode the number of iterations of the for-loop (as I believe that DF can't handle the situation in which the number of iterations is dynamically determined at run-time.) Here's some pseudocode:

```
PCollection<KV<Integer,RowVector>> rowVectors = ...
PCollectionView<Map<Integer, Float>> vectorX;

for (int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  PCollection<KV<Integer,Float>> dotProducts = 
     rowVectors.apply(ParDo.of(new DoDotProduct().withSideInputs(vectorX));
  vectorX = dotProducts.apply(View.asMap());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we only support up to 1000 transformations / stages. This would require 1000000 (or whatever your forloop iterates over) stages.

Also you are correct in that we don't allow changes to the graph after the pipeline begins running.

If you want to do less than 1000 iterations, then using a map side input can work but you have to limit the number of map lookups you do per RowVector. You can do this by ensuring that each lookup has the whole column instead of walking the map for each RowVector. In this case you'd represent your matrix as a PCollectionView of a `Map<ColumnIndex, Iterable<RowIndex, RowValue>>`